# nginx location не работает return 200

Tags: nginx

Не понятная работа location в nginx, подскажите, что не так делаю.

Настроил nginx + php-fpm: не работает `return 200`, причем работает `return 404`, `return 301`, `403`

Работает:

```
location /test {
    return 301;
}
```

Не работает

```
location /test {
    return 200;
}
```

Пытается сохранить пустую страницу

Comment: Не работает каким образом? Результаты `curl -IL http://example.com/test` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Пытается сохранить пустую страницу

Ну а что ему остаётся делать, если ты возвращаешь код и не возвращаешь тело ответа?..

```
location /test {
    return 200 'hello world';

    # можно раскомментировать эту строчку
    # если где-то в конфигах переопределён default_type
    # default_type text/html;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так работает с добавлением default_type text/html;
Делал по иструкции https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSOKmL8L2NY&ab_channel=GeekCode (1:19)  , там почему то без default_type text/html работает

Comment: @Adkondr вы смотрите и не видите - там и mime.types подключены, и `return 200` возвращается с телом ответа

Comment: так бы то ни было, пометьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог